# Python Scrapy Date Extraction Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am struggling with how to properly extract an oddly formatted date that exists on the page in one location using Python Scrapy.

**What needs to be changed to have the date included on every output row in yyyy-mm-dd format?**

> Problematic code lines:

```
data2 = response.xpath('//span[@class="tab"]/text()').get().replace(". ", "-")
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(data2, "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

> Sample output appears to contain one character for date.
> Example: {'match_id': '1893065', 'date': '0'}

> Here is the full spider.

import scrapy
import datetime
import re
from datetime import timedelta

```
class Tennis_ExplorerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tennis_explorer'
    allowed_domains = ['tennisexplorer.com']

    def daterange(start_date, end_date):
        for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
            yield start_date + timedelta(n)
    
    start_date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    end_date = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)    
    start_urls = []
    start_url='https://www.tennisexplorer.com/matches/?type=all&year='
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
        start_urls.append(single_date.strftime(start_url+"%Y&month=%m&day=%d&timezone=-6"))

    
    def parse(self, response): 
            #Extracting the content using xpath            
            self.logger.debug('callback "parse": got response %r' % response)
            data = response.xpath('//table[@class="result"]//a[contains(@href,"match-detail")]/@href').extract()
            match_id =[re.sub('^.+=','',el) for el in data]

            data2 = response.xpath('//span[@class="tab"]/text()').get().replace(". ", "-")
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(data2, "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            
            #Give the extracted content row wise
            for item in zip(match_id, date):
                #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
                scraped_info = {
                    'match_id' : item[0],
                    'date' : item[1]
                }

                #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
                yield scraped_info
```

Comment: Only some of the dates are formatted differently than what you expect?

Comment: @AMC Only one character shows up in the output. No dates are formatted correctly.

Comment: Right, yes, I confused it with the `match_id`. Have you done any debugging to narrow down the issue?

Comment: you can have problem with `zip(match_id, date)` because `match_id` is a list of ids but `date` is single string, not list of dates. But Python treats string as list of chars and `zip()` gets single char from this list. You shouldn't use `zip()` for this but normal `for match in match_id: scraped_info = { 'match_id' : match, 'date' : data}`. Or `scraped_info = { 'match_id' : match_id[0], 'date' : data}` without `for`-loop when you need only one result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a useless `datetime` in your script (`datetime.datetime.strptime`)
You can also change the date format with a regex. With `re.sub` :

```
data = "01. 01. 2008"
print(re.sub("^(\d+).+?(\d+).+(\d{4})$",'\g<3>-\g<2>-\g<1>',data))
```

Output :

```
2008-01-01
```

Regarding your problem, use `len()` to generate a list of the same length as the number of matches displayed on the webpage :

```
date = re.sub("^(\d+).+?(\d+).+(\d{4})$",'\g<3>-\g<2>-\g<1>',data)
nbel = len(response.xpath('//table[@class="result"]//a[contains(@href,"match-detail")]').extract
dates = [date]*nbel
```

Output :

```
['2008-01-01', '2008-01-01', '2008-01-01',...,'2008-01-01', '2008-01-01', '2008-01-01']
```

Depending your expected output, you can construct your dictionnary this way (dates is your list with all the dates, and ids is the list with all your ids, they have the same length) :

```
dic={}
dic["matches:"]=[]
for el in range(1,len(ids)):
    dic1={"id:":ids[el],"date":dates[el]}
    dic["matches:"].append(dic1)

print(dic)
```

Output :

```
{'matches:': [{'id:': '1893063', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893067', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893062', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893059', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893061', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893066', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893229', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893065', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893117', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893134', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893133', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893130', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893158', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893048', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893047', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893045', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893046', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893109', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893110', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893107', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893108', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893105', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893106', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893058', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893057', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893056', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893055', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893054', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893053', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893139', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893131', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893102', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893116', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893115', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893114', 'date': '2020-08-04'}, {'id:': '1893113', 'date': '2020-08-04'}]}
```

Visual output :

[image: Dic]

Comment: I received an invalid syntax error for "dates = [date]*nbel"

Comment: Ok I updated the code. You can view the updated code here: https://python-forum.io/Thread-Python-Scrapy-Date-Extraction-Issue?pid=122480#pid122480

I really appreciate your help. Truly.

Comment: No syntax errors on my end. You should specify your expected output. I've edited my post with a solution to construct the dictionary.